# How to prevent django forms removing newline characters

Tags: python, django, forms, newline, eol

How to prevent django removing the newline characters from the form text field input?

When I type this into the text field in my form:

> aaa
>
> bbb
>
> ccc

I want it it to stay like above. But instead django converts it into:

> aaa bbb ccc

I've tried overrding clean() method like this (I want multiple spaces to be removed, but not EOL characters):

```
class ThreadForm(ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        body = cleaned_data.get('body')
        body = re.sub(' +', '', body)
        cleaned_data['body'] = body

        return cleaned_data

    body = forms.CharField(max_length=25000, widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = ['title', 'posted_by']
        exclude = ['']
```

but it didn't work. any ideas?
Thanks

SOLUTION:

```
{{ value|linebreaksbr }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need [`linebreaksbr`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr)

```
{{ value|linebreaksbr }}
```

Comment: well it fits my example but when I try to pass multiple EOLs like 10, it leaves only 1 or 2.. how can I fix this? anyway thanks

Comment: okay, i found a solution. I used {{ value|linebreaksbr }} instead of {{ value|linebreaks }}